# Joomla 3.4.x: Tags are not saved

Tags: php, joomla-3.4, tags

I would like to use the tagging-function of Joomla! in my component.

To get that working I created a postflight which is being executed after installation:

```
function postflight($type, $parent)
{
    $table = JTable::getInstance('Contenttype', 'JTable');
    if(!$table->load(array('type_alias' => 'com_bestia.item')))
    {
        $common = new stdClass;
        $common->core_content_item_id = 'id';
        $common->core_title = 'title';
        $common->core_state = 'state';
        $common->core_alias = 'alias';
        $common->core_created_time = 'created';
        $common->core_modified_time = 'modified';
        $common->core_body = 'description';
        $common->core_hits = 'hits';
        $common->core_publish_up = 'publish_up';
        $common->core_publish_down = 'publish_down';
        $common->core_access = 'access';
        $common->core_params = 'params';
        $common->core_featured = 'featured';
        $common->core_metadata   = 'metadata';
        $common->core_language   = 'language';
        $common->core_images = 'images';
        $common->core_urls = 'urls';
        $common->core_version = 'version';
        $common->core_ordering   = 'ordering';
        $common->core_metakey = 'metakey';
        $common->core_metadesc = 'metadesc';
        $common->core_catid = 'catid';
        $common->core_xreference = 'xreference';
        $common->asset_id = null;
        $field_mappings = new stdClass;
        $field_mappings->common[] = $common;
        $field_mappings->special = array();
        $special = new stdClass; $special->dbtable = '#__bestia_items'; $special->key = 'id'; $special->type = 'Item'; $special->prefix = 'BestiaTable'; $special->config = 'array()';
        $table_object = new stdClass;
        $table_object->special = $special;
        $contenttype['type_title'] = 'Item';
        $contenttype['type_alias'] = 'com_bestia.item';
        $contenttype['table'] = json_encode($table_object);
        $contenttype['rules'] = '';
        $contenttype['router'] = 'BestiaHelperRoute::getBestiaRoute';
        $contenttype['field_mappings'] = json_encode($field_mappings);
        $table->save($contenttype);
    }
}
```

Also I modified my table:

```
public function __construct(&$db)
{
    parent::__construct('#__bestia_items', 'id', $db);
    JTableObserverTags::createObserver($this, array('typeAlias' => 'com_bestia.item'));
}
```

And my model:

```
/**
 * getItem function.
 * 
 * @access public
 * @param mixed $pk (default: null)
 * @return void
 */
public function getItem($pk = null)
{
    if ($item = parent::getItem($pk)) 
    {
        // Convert the metadata field to an array.
        $registry                   =       new JRegistry;

        if(isset($item->metadata))
        {
            $registry->loadString($item->metadata);
            $item->metadata         =       $registry->toArray();
        }

        if (!empty($item->id))
        {
            $item->tags             =       new JHelperTags;
            $item->tags->getTagIds($item->id, 'com_bestia.item');
            $item->metadata['tags'] =       $item->tags;
        }           
    }

    return $item;
}
```

Now I modified my form.xml:

```
    <field  name        =       "tags" 
            type        =       "tag"
            label       =       "JTAG" 
            description =       "JTAG_DESC"
            class       =       "inputbox span12 small" 
            multiple    =       "true"
            filter      =       "safehtml" />
```

Now if I want to save my item with some tags, I'm getting this error:

> Speichern fehlgeschlagen! Fehler: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found:
>   1054 Unknown column 'newTags' in 'field list'

What can I do here?

Answer (score 2):

Got the error:

Filter does not work here. Removing

```
filter      =       "safehtml"
```

solves the problem.